# UDP communication between Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, udp, communication

I'm trying to communicate a Java program with a C# one but it's not working.

The code is really basic, here it is:

This is the Java client

```
static InetAddress ip;
static int port = 10000;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port, ip);
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        sendData = "Hola".getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, ip, port);
        socket.send(sendPacket);
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

And here it is the C# server

```
static UdpClient client;
static IPEndPoint sender;
void Start () {
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    string ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port =  10000;
    client = new UdpClient(ip, port);       
    sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);

    client.BeginReceive (new AsyncCallback(recibir), sender);

}

static void recibir(IAsyncResult res){
    byte[] bResp = client.EndReceive(res, ref sender);

    //Convert the data to a string
    string mes = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bResp);

    //Display the string
    Debug.Log(mes);
}
```

The c# server is a Unity file, I mean, I execute it from Unity, so Start is the first method called.

I would like them to communicate through port 10000 (or any ohter one) in my computer, java's main and c#'s start seem to be executed but the callback is never called.

Any ideas of why it isn't working? Thank you all.

Comment: I tried also to use a blocking Receive in c# but the message was never received. So the trouble may be in the connection but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, in the Java client new DatagramSocket() must be called without any argument, and in the c# server new UdpClient(port); must be called only with the port.

Answer (score 0):

`BeginReceive()` is non-blocking. Your program terminates before it can receive anything. Either use `Receive()` or put a busy-waiting-loop at the end of the server code.

Comment: I've tried using a while(true){}, but then Unity gets blocked. I think that's because Start method never ends.